# Is it possible to limit the number of pages a long table uses?

Tags: longtable

I have a table that is longer than one page but only by like half a page, and so am using longtable to break it into 2 pages. However, the problem that I'm running into is that based on where it is in the document, latex wants to start the table at the end of a page, have 2-3 rows on that page, fill the next full page, and then put 3-4 lines on a third page.

Is there a way to either require N lines to be on any page for longtable, or to limit the number of pages it can fill for a particular table?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I used Mico's suggestion of afterpage and it works great!

Answer (score 5):

You can include the first 10 (or 12 or whatever) lines of the table before the `\endfirsthead` (or before the `\endlastfoot`) commands and then they will stick together.

Or you can use `\\*` rather than `\\` at the ends of the rows to discourage linebreaking.

Or (perhaps) you could use the `needspace` package and issue `\clearpage` if you are already near the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 4):

Still another suggestion: Load the `afterpage` package and encase the `longtable` environment in an `\afterpage{\begin{longtable}...\end{longtable}` directive. This will ensure that the table always starts at the top of a page, thereby maximizing the likelihood that the longtable will fit on two (physical) pages.